# Why is Google Chrome ignoring my proxy settings?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop.The network I am connected to uses a proxy server. I adjusted the proxy settings in System Settings->Network->Network Proxy.

I applied them system wide, but in Google Chrome it is not working. I am unable to browse although I can access the Internet through Mozilla Firefox where I set up the proxy manually.

Can any one tell me what the problem is? How I can correct it?

Comment: have you tried proxy anywhere extension?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eejcbegfnjfjnmdikkplhbhnemddchbn

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/68678/83046) might help.

Answer (score 6):

Download `dconf-tools :

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

run it from terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

Then go to "**systerm>proxy**" change "**mode**" to manual and select "**use-same-proxy**"
now goto "**system>proxy>http**" give your proxy information there and select "enable" option

make sure `ftp`, `https` and `socks` have "0" (zero) on "**port**" and nothing on "**Host**" field

Everything should work fine now.

Comment: For Unity, use `All Settings > Network > Network Proxy` for configuring system-wide proxy.

Answer (score 3):

One method of bypassing this problem is to install the Switch Proxy extension for Chromium, then set your proxy settings within the extension. Chromium will pay attention to these extension settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible reasons. Try the following:

1. Update Chrome (Run a normal software update)
2. Use [Proxy Switchy Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj)
3. Try using Chromium, as I can confirm that it uses the correct Proxy settings.

Also see [this bug report](http://crbug.com/80453) for further details.

As a workaround, you can try out these steps (from [here](http://www.gnomeshell.com/2011/04/29/old-network-proxy-settings-not-working-in-gnome3/)):

1. Install the [gconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gconf-editor/) package.
2. Start the `Configuration Editor` application
3. Go to the system -> proxy tab and set the proxy you want there.

> Make sure you set the mode value from ‘none’ to manual , and for example if you want to set a socks5 proxy set the socks_host and socks_port values.

This workaround is for the case when you have an older version of Chrome, which uses gnome2 proxy settings.

Comment: I am actually having the issues with Chromium

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a bug in upsteam chromium. (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/858252
and
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80453)

Answer (score 0):

I have spent ages trying to find an answer to this horrible problem, without result.
Every time I close Chrome, or re-boot my computer the next time I open Chrome that evil proxy setting has changed. I have e-mailed Chrome technical help but they don't reply.

But I have found a solution. As Chrome says, go to settings, show advanced settings, proxy settings, change proxy settings, LAN settings, and un tick 'use proxy server ...'

But now, the key thing is, do not close these last 2 little windows. Leave them open. As long as they are open that effing malware virus does not activate. You can continue with Chrome without proxy problem. 
Until, that is, you close those little windows or re-boot the computer. In which case you have to go through the process again.
In other words, so long as you keep those little windows open you won't have a proxy problem.

I Hate Chrome for not having found a better solution for this yet.