# Where to set proxy ignore list?

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, networking, proxy

I upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04, shocked to see few things...

My system is behind a proxy, so I did set a proxy setting. Being a web developer, I want to remove a lot of addresses that I type in browser address bar to not hit proxy. There's no such ignore list in ubuntu 11.10, what/where do I do it? What was the requirement to change the way network gui worked?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found a hint to the solution in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857338), where a user sent a link to [Gnome Developer Center](http://developer.gnome.org/ProxyConfiguration/) explaining the configuration for Gnome Shell. My solution explains what to do for Unity.

You will need to install **dconf-tools** if you don't have it yet:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then run the tool (for example, pressing *Ctrl+F2*, then typing *dconf-editor* and pressing *Enter*).

Expand the key **system** on the left pane and click on the **proxy** key. On the right pane you will get the place to enter the list of ignored proxies (**ignore-hosts**).

In the key *proxy* and subkeys of it (*ftp*, *http*, *https* and *socks*) you can configure more proxy options that are not available in the new-shiny-but-almost-useless GUI.

Don't forget to log out and log in again to make the configuration active!

The only difference for Unity compared with Gnome Shell is that the keys to be modified for Gnome Shell are in the org.gnome.system.proxy key.

Comment: BTW, you might want to amend "dconf" to "dconf-editor", otherwise thanks!

Comment: @khoomeister: thank you for your comment! I already corrected the mentioned command.

Comment: great - although many third party softwares don't honor those settings yet :(

Comment: Hello, I recently see this post, install the dconf editor and filled the options. But now I can log in in to my account. Any Idea