# How to set exceptions for proxy in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: proxy, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to set proxy ignore list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list)

I am using Internet through proxy server of our organization. But I don't want to use the proxy server when opening my local websites published in my own web server in localhost. How can I set exceptions for proxy in Ubuntu 11.10?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use proxy settings for localhost, add localhost to "Ignore host list" on **Network Proxy Preferences** Window (Click the ubuntu icon on left and serch for proxy).
Or If you are using firefox, You can go to Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings(button) then enter localhost in "No Proxy for" text box.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But there is no Ignore host list in Ubuntu 11.10 at all.