# Proxy exceptions in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, networking, proxy

How do I setup **proxy** exceptions under **Ubuntu 12.04**?

Already tried the proposed solutions for earlier Ubuntu versions and none seem to work. There is no Network Proxy Preferences in **12.04 AFAIK**.

`System Settings` -> `Network` -> `Network Proxy` does not offer the possibility to add exceptions.

Is there a file where these settings reside so I can edit them manually and add exceptions (and so the settings are honored by all network apps)?

I would really appreciate any info on this one not already mentioned on earlier answers, as none of theme worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Alex: the main/regular interface could be a lot better if there was a text field for the ignore list. Anyways: for those using 12.10, there is no gconf-editor. Only the dconf-editor will help.

Answer (score 13):

You use either **gconf-editor /system/http_proxy/ignore_hosts**
or **dconf-editor** (and manually navigate to system -> http_proxy -> ignore_hosts).

Contrary to what others wrote, there is no need to re-login for changes to take effect.
Moreover, settings done for /system/http_proxy/ignore_hosts also take effect for https.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with 12.04 and the solution given on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks nvk, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list) finally worked for me too, but there is a catch:

In dconf-editor there is a help text that reads something like 'if no configuration for **https** is given, the proxy server configured for **http** will be used for **https** too'. This is not true, at least for **Ubuntu 12.04**. I had to add the server for all protocols, even being the same one for **http**, **ftp** and **https**. After I did this, and after a logging off and in again, proxies (including exceptions) took effect for all applications.

Still, I think the 'normal' network settings GUI could be made better by the addition of an extra input box for the proxy exceptions in the proxies settings part. I hope to see this in a future Ubuntu update.