# Cannot add proxy exceptions on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, 15.04, proxy

My machine sits behind office network proxy.

How can I add exception for certain hosts?

I have tried the solution given in [Proxy exceptions in 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135089/proxy-exceptions-in-12-04-lts). In gconf-editor it does not show 'ignore_hosts' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is available via `gconf-editor`

[image]

or with `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

[image]

or via your Network sessings

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The snapshots were very useful. I got the stuff working.  But I still don't see the 'ignore hosts' in 'network settings'.

Comment: In your network settings?

Comment: @DeeptiK: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

This option IS there. *system -> proxy -> ignore-hosts*

Comment: I have just checked it on 15.04.

Comment: Your path is wrong `/system/http_proxy/ignore_hosts`

Comment: Checked again. `/system/proxy/ignore-hosts` The `http` is under proxy. Are you still looking in `gconf`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/14LJwL1

Comment: I'm in Russia, imgur is forbidden here. OK, forget it...

Comment: @BarafuAlbino Bullshit about imgur. I am in Russia too. It may be forbidden by someone else.

Comment: May be. My internet provider just returned the usual "Forbidden by officials" stub page.