# no-proxy includes ports?

Tags: proxy

Referred to [Proxy exceptions in 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135089/proxy-exceptions-in-12-04-lts) and http://xmodulo.com/how-to-configure-http-proxy-exceptions.html
But they didn't mention ports

in "`/etc/environment`,"

```
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com, 1.2.3.4"
```

Does 1.2.3.4 also include 1.2.3.4:8080, 1.2.3.4:5000 or do I have to specify the ports as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran through and I believe that does it.
But if you are reaching by hostname defined in "`/etc/hosts`" you have to list out that as well.