# Ignoring local addresses on proxy server

Tags: 16.04, networking, proxy

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have an internet connection provided by the university, which has a proxy setting. I want to access the local addresses but am unable to visit.
I tried what was told here: [Where to set proxy ignore list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68089/where-to-set-proxy-ignore-list) but I still was unable to connect to those addresses.

This is my dconf-editor setting:

[image: dconf-editor]